# Horizontal offset for beamer sidebar

Tags: beamer, presentations, sidebar

Is there any way to offset the sidebar in beamer horizontally? I couldn't find anything in Beamer documentation. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "offset horizontally", and which sidebar? Please provide the code of a small example document that has this sidebar and try to make clear what you want to change, in text or by adding a mock-up screenshot (edited in Paint or similar) to your question.